# (place)に(noun)を(verb)に行きます construction

Tags: grammar, particles

is there much of a difference between these two sentences:

1. 山にハイキングに行きます
2. 山にハイキングをしに行きます

Also, can 'ni' be replaced with 'de' in sentences such as 町（に・で）映画を見に行きます